# Change img src on hover with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

My code is in PHP and I would want to change the image button1.png to button2.png on hover. The image should still be clickable.

```
$link = "<a class='wplink' href='something' title='something' rel='nofollow'>". "<img src='button1.png' />" ."</a>";
```

Comment: `src` is not a CSS style, it's a DOM attribute. You need to use Javascript.

Comment: I found this answer: <img src="a.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='b.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='a.jpg'" />  Could this work?

Comment: Yes, that's Javascript.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it will do.

The onmouseout and onmouseover should be on the hyperlink tag.

```
$link = "<a class='wpfp-link' href='?wpfpaction=".$action."&amp;postid=". $post_id . "' title='". $opt ."' rel='nofollow' onmouseover=\"document.but.src='".WPFP_PATH."/vault-button2.png'\" onmouseout=\"document.but.src='".WPFP_PATH."/vault-button1.png'\">
```

";

Comment: It sends me to a blank page. :/

Comment: I figured it out now! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @caiolopes . It worked for me als..,  We can also use hover like this ` a:hover {background-color: yellow;} `.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
echo $link = "<a class='wpfp-link' href='?wpfpaction=".$action."&postid=". $post_id . "' title='". $opt ."' rel='nofollow' onmouseover='javascript:document.getElementById(\"but\").src=\"".WPFP_PATH."/vault-button2.png\"' onmouseout='javascript:document.getElementById(\"but\").src=\"".WPFP_PATH."/vault-button1.png\"' > <img src='".WPFP_PATH."/vault-button1.png' name='but' id='but'/></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("img").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).attr("src","img2.png");
});
```